# Problem with Rounding off to nearest 0.05 value

Tags: java, double, decimal, rounding

There are already [so many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+0.05) asked about this already.

One popular answer is to use the below formula.

```
  Math.ceiling(myValue * 20) / 20
```

I need the following output for corresponding input.

```
     16.489 (input)   - 16.49(output)
```

Using the above formula

```
     16.489*20  = 329.78

     Math.ceil(329.78) = 330.0

     and 330.0 /20  = 16.5
```

but what I want is 16.49.

Ideally the Math.ceil stuff should have given 329.8

So how do we get around the above case? There are many other cases similar to this.

Comment: 16.49, rounded to the nearest 0.05, is 16.50; are you wanting a value rounded to the nearest 0.005?

Comment: the question fails so bad at math :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of multiplying / dividing with 2*10, you should do it with 10<sup>2</sup>.

However, I suggest you use `Math.round(100*a) / 100.0`, or if you need it for printing, `printf` or `DecimalFormat`.

**Examples:**

```
double input = 16.489;

// Math.round
System.out.println(Math.round(100 * input) / 100.0);

// Decimal format
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(input));

// printf
System.out.printf("%.2f", input);
```

**Output**:

```
16.49
16.49
16.49
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Math.round()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)
 to format your value?

edit:   Math.round(value * 100.0) / 100.0;

Comment: That rounds off 0.5. He needs 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) would help you.This link gives you a discussion on how to round off a number to the n-th decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding 16.489 up to the nearest 0.05 is correctly 16.5, with 16.45 being the next lowest possible value.

The behaviour seen is correct. If you want to be able to round up to the nearest 0.01 then

`Math.ceiling(myValue * 100) / 100`

would be a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
round(16.489, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);

public static double round(double x, int scale, int roundingMethod) {
        try {
            return (new BigDecimal
                   (Double.toString(x))
                   .setScale(scale, roundingMethod))
                   .doubleValue();
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            if (Double.isInfinite(x)) {
                return x;
            } else {
                return Double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
```